# how to install apache phoenix to ambari 1.7 with hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm new to hadoop. I want to install phoenix with hbase but I have installed hadoop cluster using ambari 1.7 on ubuntu. I'm not able to find any tutorial to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build up your own Hadoop stack:
https://phoenix.apache.org/download.html
https://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html

If you use e.g. IBM Open Platform (which is for free btw):
https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/blog/2015/10/21/installing-apache-phoenix-ibm-open-platform-apache-hadoop-4-1/

Answer (score 0):

hbase should be available as service under add service button on home page.
For installing phoenix i used this link 
http://dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2-trunk/bk_installing_manually_book/content/upgrade-22-7-a.html

basically yum install phoenix on each node and then create soft links to the phoenix server jar file
hth